# UITabbarController Navigation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

My requirement is when ever i press the "**Save**" button(what ever i marked in above image) immediately i want to navigate to "First ViewController" with Enable of "1 First" Bar item like:

[image]

I used code like:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtnClicked:(id)sender {
   FirstViewController *firstViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstViewController"];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES ];
  }
```

But here i am pushing the screen(Back button also visible & Bar Item not enable )

How can i approach this. Can you please help me out regarding this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i use code like:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtnClicked:(id)sender {
  UINavigationController *navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
  self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = navController;
}

**(or)**

- (IBAction)saveBtnClicked:(id)sender {
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I got the proper answer

Answer (score 0):

try this, this should work:

```
- (IBAction)saveBtnClicked:(id)sender {
        UINavigationController *firstTabNavController = self.tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers[0];
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [firstTabNavController viewControllers];
        while(viewController.count > 1){
            [viewControllers removeLastObject];
        }
        firstTabNavController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
        self.tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting crash like:: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fda73cb9520'======>   I am unable to understand this::         NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [firstTabNavController viewControllers];

Comment: Just confirm, if you are having navigation controller or navigation controller in [tabbarcontroller viewcontrollers]. If it is viewcontroller, then  you can only call self.tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = 1; only.

Comment: Firstly, I created one "Firstview controller" and i gave connection to Editor->Embeded in -> Tabbar controller  and after that i created one more view controller"Second View Controller". here i gave connection like UITabbar controller to Second Viewcontroller with "Viewcontroller" segue after that i enable navigation controller for both classes"First view controller & second view controller"

Comment: can you try to print self.tabbarcontroller.viewcontrollers, and check what it displays: navigationcontrollers or viewcontrollers. If it shows navigationcontrollers, then above code will work else try only self.tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = 1;

Comment: Printing description of viewControllers:
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa01ade6060>(
<FirstViewController: 0x7fa01ac3ae70>
)==>  i am getting warning like:: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSArray<__kindof UIViewController *> *'

Comment: just try - (IBAction)saveBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    self.tabbarcontroller.selectedIndex = 1;
} only in your code, it will work. As per your logs it contains viewcontrollers only.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other view controllers in the first tab's stack, then you should be able to simply use:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

If there are other view controllers in the stack, you will need to use popToRoot after changing the tab index.