# Go to detail view controller in another tab?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tabs, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app with multiple tabs. On one tab my user can select a button which will lead them to another tab, but it will be a detail view controller there.

So I have on tab 1 a button where the user can go to the second tab.

On tab 2 I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` set as `rootViewController`, where I need to land on a detail `UIViewController`.

I don't know how I can do this the right way.

I could create a static (or `class`) variable in the rootViewController of my second tab that will tell me if I need to push the detailViewController.

But I have multiple detail view controllers, which means that if I switch to the correct tab, I could go to a detail viewcontroller, which means that the static variable in that rootviewcontroller won't matter until I go back to that rootviewcontroller.

Any ideas on how I can improve my setup? (I am using separate storyboards for each tab, to reduce merge conflicts)

Comment: Forgive me, but you have a button on tab1 screen to open another tab2? The same as pressing the second tab at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868675/uitabbarcontroller-navigation-issue/34868821?noredirect=1#comment57477090_34868821

Comment: @AnkitThakur that is not exactly what I need, I have 1 level deeper. I will make a screenshot of an example storyboard tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Call this method on your button click from tab1. This will add your DetailViewController in navigation stack of your second tab.

```
#pragma mark- Injecting middle view controller

-(void)showDetailViewControllerInjectingMiddleViewController {

  // get navigation controller for your 2nd tab

  UINavigationController *navigationController = [[((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController) viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]; // 1 is for second tab
  NSMutableArray *controllers = [navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

 [controllers addObject: [self prepareMiddleViewController]];
 [controllers addObject:[self prepareDestinationViewController]];

 [navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:NO];

 [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

 }


-(UIViewController *)prepareMiddleViewController {

 UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:rootViewIdentifier];
 return rootViewController;

}

-(UIViewController *)prepareDestinationViewController {

 UIViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:detailViewIdentifier];
 return detailViewController;

}
```